# RadComboBox with Checkbox enabled - Showing only first checked Item even I select different item

Tags: c#, telerik

I use Telerik RadComboBox with Checkbox enabled. When I check one item and click any where to lost focus, then again I select another items from same combobox then it display only first item text in combobox.

Can some one help me for this problem.

Comment: Is this ASP.NET or WPF ?

Comment: In addition to the details asked by @XAMlMAX, it's helpful to post some code

Comment: Try removing Filter property

Comment: Answer XAML or ASP.NEt -1

Answer (score 1):

You probably use Filter also, that's why you face this problem. Add the property

> AllowCustomText = "true"

e.x That works perfectly

```
<telerik:RadComboBox ID="id" runat="server" Width="60%" Skin="MetroTouch" CheckBoxes="true" Filter="Contains" CheckedItemsTexts="FitInInput" AllowCustomText="true">
                                        </telerik:RadComboBox>
```

There is a solution found [here](https://www.telerik.com/forums/possible-bug-with-checkboxes-true-and-filter-contains)